# Issue with Scrapy: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to learn how web scraping works using python. I'm attempting to use Scrapy to gather some data from morningstar website. Essentially, I would like the program to read my csv file with a row of morningstar url. I then need the program to parse the "Other Classes Info" table on Morningstar. My issue is I keep getting: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min). Any help would be appreciated.

**morningSpider.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from .. import items
from scrapy.http import Request
import csv

def get_urls_from_csv():
     with open("C:\Users\kate\Desktop\morningStar\morningTest.csv", 'r') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f)
        scrapurls = []
        for row in data:
            for column in row:
                 scrapurls.append(column)
        return scrapurls

class morningSpider(Spider):
    name = "morningSpider"
    allowed_domains = []
    #start_urls = scrapurls

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item',   
        follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.http.Request(url=start_url) for start_url in get_urls_from_csv()]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table[@class="r_table1 text2"]//table/tr')[1:]:
            item = items.SpiderItem
            item['FundName'] = row.select("td[2]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['FrontLoad'] = row.select("td[3]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['DeferredLoad'] = row.select("td[4]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['ExpenseRatio'] = row.select("td[5]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['MinInitPurchase'] = row.select("td[6]/text()").extract([0]
            item['Actual'] = row.select("td[7]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['PurchaseConstraint'] = row.select("td[8]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['ShareClassAttributes'] = row.select("td[9]/text()").extract()[0]
            yield item
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MorningItem(Item):
       # define the fields for your item here like:
       # name = scrapy.Field()
       FundName = Field()
       FrontLoad = Field()
       DeferredLoad = Field()
       ExpenseRatio = Field()
       MinInitPurchase = Field()
       Actual = Field()
       PurchaseConstraint = Field()
       ShareClassAttributes = Field()
       pass
```

**Output**

```
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: morningScrape)
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'morningScrape.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':    
['morningScrape.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'morningScrape'}
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider,  TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middleware:
HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware,     
Retry Middleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware,   
HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware,   
ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:  
HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware,   
UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on    

2015-11-29 18:46:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET   
SOMEURL> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to 
show all duplicates)
2015-11-29 18:46:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET     
ANOTHERURL> (referer: None)
2015-11-29 18:46:27 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-11-29 18:46:27 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:  
{'downloader/request_bytes': 267,
'downloader/request_count': 1,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
'downloader/response_bytes': 8691,
'downloader/response_count': 1,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 29, 23, 46, 27, 255000),
'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 29, 23, 46, 26, 848000)}
2015-11-29 18:46:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you should be sharing those urls, but checking the ones on the log I see that first that xpath isn't getting any items, and the second url isn't of public access.

Then you are overriding the `parse` method which is necessary for `CrawlSpider` which is the one that uses `rules`, but you are using a `Spider` which doesn't use the rules so they won't apply to your crawling.

Also if you change `Spider` to `CrawlSpider`, that rule can't have `follow=True` and `callback!=None`, because they are opposites.

Answer (score 0):

1. as post by @eLRuLL you should use `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider`
2. > 0 pages

   isn't matter.
   See `dupefilter/filtered` in the log. That means your url has been filtered.
   See `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` settings in `scrapy.settings.default_settings`,  overwrite this settings to prevent filter.